# Argument matrix row operations (3x4)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Background**

Given the argument matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & -5 & 3\\4 & 10  & -6  & -4\\-4 & -14 & -4 & -5\end{bmatrix}$$

perform each row operation in the order specified and enter the final result.

**My work so far**

a) First: $R2→R2-4R1$

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -2 & 14 & -16\end{bmatrix}$$

b) Second: $R3→R3+4R1$

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -2 & -24 & 7\end{bmatrix}$$

Am I on the right track here? I'm using RREF to work these out.

Comment: what is the "order specified"?

Comment: What exactly is your aim here? I am not sure.

Comment: It's written above. Solve first for R2→R2−4R1, then second, R3→R3+4R1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on exactly the right track!  The only thing is when you do a row (column) operation, that row isn't isolated, it becomes that row (column) in the new matrix.  That is, $R_2 \rightarrow R_2 - 4R_1$ gives
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & -5 & 3 \\ 0 & -2 & 14 & -4 \\ -4 & -14 & -4 & -5 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Then, when you perform the next operation, the same thing happens with the next row.  That is $R_3 \rightarrow R_3 + 4R_1$ gives
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & -5 & 3 \\ 0 & -2 & 14 & -4 \\ 0 & -2 & -24 & 7 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Keep up the good work!